# How to use Kettle to handle the linefeed in a field

Tags: etl, pentaho, kettle

I want to use Kettle to handle a data set.
The format of the data set is as below

```
product/productId: B00006HAXW
review/userId: A1RSDE90N6RSZF
review/profileName: Joseph M. Kotow
review/helpfulness: 9/9
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1042502400
review/summary: Pittsburgh - Home of the OLDIES
review/text: I have all of the doo wop DVD's and this one is as good or better than the
1st ones. Remember once these performers are gone, we'll never get to see them again.
Rhino did an excellent job and if you like or love doo wop and Rock n Roll you'll LOVE
this DVD !!
```

I read every line of the data first and then transform every eight rows into a record.
However, there is such data:

```
review/profileName: nancy "crzyfnyfrog
I love my purple pigtails."
```

This field contains a linefeed and I don't know how to handle it.

Now I use the script code to achieve the function I want, but I still want to know how to use based components to solve it.

Comment: Did you try using the 'String Operations' step, with the option 'Remove Special Character - line feed (LF)'. Also remember, your file can be WindowsOS (LF+CR) or Unix (LF).

Comment: @CristianCurti But when I use the "Text File Input", it read each line as a field. It already removes the LF, and the problem is that the surplus lines make the format wrong when I use "Row Flattener" to generate the record.